# Create a column of differences in 'col2' for each item in 'col1'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    'col2' : [9.6,10.4, 11.2, 3.3, 6, 4, 1.94, 15.44, 6.17, 8.16]
})
```

It has the display :

```
col1    col2
0   A   9.60
1   A   10.40
2   A   11.20
3   B   3.30
4   B   6.00
5   B   4.00
6   C   1.94
7   C   15.44
8   C   6.17
9   D   8.16
```

I want to get the following output:

```
col1    col2    Diff
0   A   9.60    0
1   A   10.40   0.80
2   A   11.20   0.80
3   B   3.30    0
4   B   6.00    2.70
5   B   4.00    -2.00
6   C   1.94    0
7   C   15.44   13.50
8   C   6.17    -9.27
9   D   8.16    0
```

I tried to use `diff()` but it calculate differences for all values in `col2` however I want to do that for each `item` in `col1`.

So far I tried `df['col2'].diff()` but not worked,

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to group by col1? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html

Comment: @TiTo I don't think that groupby works, since it doesn't provide `difference` option

Comment: it does. I posted the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` and `diff()`and assign the result to the new column `Diff`. Than you only need to `fillna(0)`:

```
df['Diff'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].diff().fillna(0)
```

That should solve your problem:

```
    col1    col2    Diff
0   A   9.60    0.00
1   A   10.40   0.80
2   A   11.20   0.80
3   B   3.30    0.00
4   B   6.00    2.70
5   B   4.00    -2.00
6   C   1.94    0.00
7   C   15.44   13.50
8   C   6.17    -9.27
9   D   8.16    0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a groupby, this works i think :

```
df.insert(2, 'Diff', (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].diff()))
```

result :

```
    col1    col2    Diff
0   A   9.60    NaN
1   A   10.40   0.80
2   A   11.20   0.80
3   B   3.30    NaN
4   B   6.00    2.70
5   B   4.00    -2.00
6   C   1.94    NaN
7   C   15.44   13.50
8   C   6.17    -9.27
9   D   8.16    NaN
```

(you can replace the NaN by 0 if you wish)

Comment: Cleaner than my suggestion, nice!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
differences = []

for val in df.col1.unique():
    diffs = df.loc[df.col1 == val].col2.diff()
    differences.extend(diffs)
```

Then you can add the `differences` list as a new column.